# Does executing a child pom cause the parents' modules to build?

Tags: maven

I am reading through a [project of many pom files](https://github.com/Jasig/uPortal). These are some of them:

- A - uPortal/pom.xml
- B - uPortal/uportal-portlets-overlay/pom.xml
- C - uPortal/uportal-portlets-overlay/Announcements/pom.xml
- D - uPortal/uportal-war/pom.xml
- E - uPortal/uportal-ear/pom.xml

There relationships as follows:

- A has a modules tag with B, D, and E in it
- B references A as a parent pom
- B has a modules tag with C in it
- C references B as a parent pom
- D references A as a parent pom
- E references A as a parent pom
- E used to include C as a dependency, but now it is commented out

I also have an ant build.xml with two targets (as well as others):

- deploy-ear - runs `mvn install` on E and then deploys it
- deploy-war - runs `mvn install` on D and then deploys it

So, my question is,

1) When running ant deploy-ear (mvn install on E), does it run mvn install on C? Does the parent relationship with A cause A's modules to run and therefore causes B's modules to run, which include C?

2) Same question with deploy-war: When running ant deploy-war (mvn install on D), does it run mvn install on C via the parent relationship with A?

I have read [maven page on pom inheritance vs aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) but I am unclear on how aggregation is triggered.

Comment: If you have Maven why do you use Ant? Does not make sense...?

Comment: If you have a multi module build you should run the command only from parent and not from within modules...And remove that ant build it does not make sense...EAR/WAR can simply being done with Maven...so is a question of consistency and using only a single tool. Furthermore if you start your build from root and having all in Maven the problem you are asking for is simply solved...